# How to deploy a create-react-app to a web host (ex. Siteground)?

Tags: reactjs, github, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, create-react-app

I'm building a react project using create-react-app and am trying to figure out how to deploy my code to my hosting server on Siteground.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?  Do I import my build folder through FTP? Can I automate the process through GitHub?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

Per the [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) docs, you run `npm run build` and basically just take the output and FTP it to your web server.

However your question is very broad -- you could automate through GitHub or some other tool, but that's really going to beg opinionated responses on StackOverflow (which isn't the right forum for those kinds of questions).

Answer (score 6):

`npm run build` or `yarn build`

Builds the app for production to the `build folder`.
It correctly bundles React in production mode and optimizes the build for the best performance.

`npm run build` creates a build directory with a production build of your app. Set up your favorite HTTP server so that a visitor to your site is served index.html, and requests to static paths like `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` are served with the contents of the `/static/js/main.<hash>.js` file.

source: [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

Answer (score 5):

I just uploaded my create-react-app to siteground with FileZilla here is the step by step:

1. Once you have it all production ready `npm run build`
2. Open siteGround on your browser and into myAcount section click on `go to cPanel` scroll down and find `FTP Accounts`
3. create a new account pointing to the directory `public_html`
4. once created, it will appear down below and all the way to the right click on `configure FTP client` and under manual setting you've got what you need to connnect
5. open FileZilla and in file go to `siteManager` then `new site`
6. `host`(in filezilla) === `FTP server` (in sitiGround), `port` set it as siteground port , protocol and encryption leave it as default
7. `Logon Type` set as normal , `user` === `FTP user`(siteGround) and `password` the one you've used to create that FTP user
8. click on `connect` and paste the **content** of `yourApp/build` (from the left side that is your PC) to (the folder at the right hand side) that is your `public_html in siteGround`

That's it! go to your website and check, the react app should be displayed there

here is the source of this procedure
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/
Here they use quick connect for fileZilla though, I have more than one site so siteManager is cleaner and stores your credentials for next time

Answer (score 2):

Usually there are guided strategies from host vendors.

Example:

[Heroku Create React App Build](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

[S3 Cloudfront](https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af)

Otherwise you'll have to manage it by yourself, registering a custom build script that acts with:

> npm run build

And then move the build folder. If you use Maven you can manage the entire build with plugins like:

[Frontend Maven Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `create-react-app`, then you could do:

1. `npm run build` or `yarn build`
2. Copy everything that is inside of the `build` folder as a result of the previous point
3. In order to get the routes working, add `.htaccess` file with the following content:

   > ```
   > <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   >   RewriteEngine On
   >   RewriteBase /
   >   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   >   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   >   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   >   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   >   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
   > </IfModule>
   > ```
4. Export it to the root folder of your server (normally public_html)

[Check this great article for more info :)](https://medium.com/@aforamitrai/how-to-deploy-react-app-on-shared-hosting-cpanel-d682b0342424)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have problem deploying on siteground as well the simple solution is to have a git repo for your build and setup your public_html folder on siteground to track that git repo.

make sure to also create

`.htaccess`

with the content something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

If you don't have that your routing won't work

Also remember to go **Tools->Speed->Caching** and flush the cache if you have deployed otherwise before

Comment: I also found that I need to to flush the cache after every deploy. I'd expect siteground to notice that I uploaded new files and keep serving them from the cache. I wonder if there is a way around this (without losing the advantages of caching).